# I am trying to execute a separate java file, using cmd commands, in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, process, boot

```
String command = "java D:/code.java < D:/input.txt";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

When this part of the code is triggered, the thread keeps on waiting for the input, it is not able to take input from the 'input.txt' file.
But when running an explicit command in the cmd terminal, the same command works perfectly fine.

Comment: (This comment from a linux user, but I think Windows behaves similarly).  When you type in the command interactively, you're typing it to cmd.exe,  for which '<' is meaningful; cmd will run java for you with redirected input.  When you exec java, there is no cmd.exe involvement, so there's nothing to interpret '<'.   Change your command to exec cmd, with the java command as argument to cmd.

Comment: Can you please explain, using an example, Thanks for your response!

Comment: `command = "cmd /c java D:/code.java < D:/input.txt"`

Comment: this is working in only windows, when I tried to execute the same code in Linux environment, the error is thrown, " io exception: "cmd" no such file or directory found"

Comment: Of course you can't execute Windows commands in Linux.  As soon as you write code to run particular commands, you're in OS-specific territory. Under Linux, you'd need to run some shell to get '<' support. For what it's worth, you can't use the Windows-style drive letters shown in your command string, either.

Comment: You can avoid the whole '<' issue by using ProcessBuilder rather than Runtime.exec, and running java directly rather than via a command interpreter.  ProcessBuilder allows you to specify the source of standard input.